# Unable to access AWS S3 parquet file from AWS Lambda using duckdb

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, duckdb

I have a parquet file stored in AWS S3. Assume the location is `s3://bucket/file.parquet`. I defined a function in AWS Lambda to access this parquet file by using the code below.

```
    import os
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        import duckdb
        con = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:', read_only=False)
        home_directory = "/tmp/duckdb/"
        if not os.path.exists(home_directory):
            os.mkdir(home_directory)
    
        con.query("SET home_directory='/tmp/duckdb/';")
        con.query("INSTALL 'httpfs';")
        con.query("LOAD 'httpfs';")
        con.query("SET s3_access_key_id='xxx';")
        con.query("SET s3_secret_access_key='xxx;")
        con.query("SET s3_region='us-east-1';")
        sql = "select * from read_parquet('s3://bucket/file.parquet') limit 5;"
        data = con.execute(sql).fetchall()
        print(data)
```

When running the above code, I see the following error.

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "HTTP Error: HTTP GET error on 's3://bucket/file.parquet' (HTTP 400)",
  "errorType": "HTTPException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 140, in lambda_handler\n    data = con.execute(sql).fetchall()\n"
  ]
}
```

If I replace the `s3` url with `https` signed url, this code works fine. I also tried using boto3 library to download file on the container of Lambda and run the code and it works fine. My question is why it is failing if I pass the S3 path directly to `read_parquet` function as it is supported as per the duckdb docs.

https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/httpfs.html#s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I was able to figure out the issue. Whenever you are trying to access files from S3, we do not need to explicitly specify the following parameters in Lambda function. The credentials are picked directly from the inheriting IAM role. The moment it finds credentials as part of the code, it gets confused. Removing the lines below got rid of the error.

```
        con.query("SET s3_access_key_id='xxx';")
        con.query("SET s3_secret_access_key='xxx;")
        con.query("SET s3_region='us-east-1';")
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing what the issue was. It is not accurate that you cannot use raw credentials in Lambda, and there is a use case for this. There must have been another issue with your credentials. But you are correct you should be able to inherit the permission of the Lambda execution role too. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the code in your post, but maybe it got there when you reformated removing your keys from your code. Try changing the line

`con.query("SET s3_secret_access_key='xxx;")`

To

`con.query("SET s3_secret_access_key='xxx';")`

The 400 error usually means something in signing your S3 request is wrong. So a typo in your keys there would do it.

Also, how are you getting your access and secret keys? Are you assuming a role and need to add your session token as well? That could cause a bad signature as well. Maybe add a session token if you have it.

`SET s3_session_token='<AWS session token>';`

If that isn't it can you add the version of DuckDB to your question?